# Dynamically Pass Form ID Into Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have several forms on a page and i want to utilize the same ajax function.  It works great for one form since I am grabbing the id with `getElementById` and then passing it to my ajax function.  What I am trying to do is pass down the id of the form onSubmit dynamically.

**form**

```
<form id="postData" name="business" method="post" action="{{ path('location_graph', {'location_id': location.getId }) }}"
      class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right">
    <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
        <label class="col-2 col-form-label required" for="description">Business
            Description</label>
        <div class="col-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control m-input" id="description"
                   name="extra[description]">
        </div>
    </div>

    ...

    <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn m-btn--square btn-outline-primary">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**script**

```
document.getElementById('postData').addEventListener('submit', postData);

function postData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr("method"),
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#success__para').html("You data was saved");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Add an attribute to the form `data-form-id="form1"` and then in the javascript `var formId = $(this).data('form-id');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a `submit` event handler to each of the forms and pass `event` and `this.id` (the `id` of the form element) as arguments.

Javascript:

```
function postData(event, id) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var elem = $('#'+id);
    $.ajax({
        type: elem.attr("method"),
        url: elem.attr("action"),
        data: elem.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#success__para').html("You data was saved");
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="someid" onsubmit="postData(event, this.id)">
```